# Python - 52 card playing deck shorthand notation. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing an assignment for an intro to programming class(Python) and for my assignment I have to grab the shorthand notation of a 52 card playing deck and make the program spit out the long notation. (ie: Queen of Hearts)

Except I'm stuck and not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
#taking the shorthand notation of a 52 card playing deck
#and converting it to the long notation
cardValues = {"A": "Ace",
              "J": "Jack",
              "Q": "Queen",
              "K": "King",
              "2": "Two",
              "3": "Three",
              "4": "Four",
              "5": "Five",
              "6": "Six",
              "7": "Seven",
              "8": "Eight",
              "9": "Nine",
              "10": "Ten"}

cardSuit = {"D": "Diamonds",
            "H": "Hearts",
            "S": "Spades",
            "C": "Clubs"}

#grabbing short hand notation
print("Enter card notation: ")
cardNotation = input()


def conversion(cardValues,cardSuit):
    if len(cardNotation) == 2:
        value = cardNotation[0]
        color = cardNotation[-1]
        print (cardValues.get(value) + " of " + cardSuit.get(color))

    #for 10
    elif len(cardNotation) == 3:
        value = cardNotation[:1]
        color = cardNotation[-1]
        print (cardValues.get(value) + " of " + cardSuit.get(color))

    #failsafe
    else:
        print ("INVALID VALUE")
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing `cardNotation[0:]` gives you the entire string instead of just one letter, which is what I assume you want. You should be indexing the first letter instead, so it should be `cardNotation[0]`. That's because when you use a colon in indexing it says "from the index I'm putting in the brackets to the end of the string". Apply that same reasoning to `[1:]` and get the correct index for color.

Comment: Even with the changes to the indexing, I'm getting either a "is not defined" error or  "invalid syntax" depending on what I put in the input.(all letters come out as "is not defined" [QS] : with numerals it's "invalid syntax"[6H])
Would this mean I would have to write an if statement for it being a int or a str?

changes:
    if len(cardNotation) == 2:
        value = cardNotation[0]
        color = cardNotation[-1]
        print (cardValues.get(value) + " of " + cardSuit.get(color))

    elif len(cardNotation) == 3:
        value = cardNotation[:1]
        color = cardNotation[-1]

Comment: Just in case you haven't solved it yet: I put your code into my python editor and it came out fine. The only change I made to it was your function signature `def conversion(cardValues, cardSuit):`, which I changed to `def conversion(cardNotation):`. `cardValues` and `cardSuit` are not defined and are taken directly from `cardNotation`, so you shouldn't use those as parameters.